# Link drop down menu to update automatically cell values when selecting in the menu

Tags: microsoft-excel, dropdownlist

I have created a drop-down menu that has all the name of all the tabs other than the one I am working in V1-V10.

I am trying to get the linked cells below in the form to update automatically with the values in tab V2 when I select V2 in the drop-down menu, but this does not work.

I have tried using code `=$A$8!C5` ex but get an error message `C5` will become `C6` etc.

[image]

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239)

Comment: Is that "error" because you are copying your formula down? That is expected behavior. You'll need to edit your question to tell us what you are doing and  want/expect to have happen. Maybe then someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand the goal you are trying to accomplish, the following formula should work:

=INDIRECT("'"&$A$8&"'!"&"C5")

The text is concatenated within the INDIRECT function to give you **'V1'!C5**; the INDIRECT function will then return the contents of the V1 tab, cell C5. Note the single apostrophe within the first set of quote marks, and the single apostrophe before the ! within the second set of quote marks.

Based on the way the question is phrased, it is unclear if you always want to reference cell C5 in the other tab. If yes, use the formula above. If you always want to reference column C in the other tab, but you want to reference the row in the selected tab corresponding to the row you are currently on in the Skjema tab, then you could use this formula instead:

=INDIRECT("'"&$A$8&"'!"&"C"&ROW())

This formula can be copied down the column - when placed in row 5 of the Skjema tab it will give you cell C5 from the tab selected in the drop down. When placed in row 6 of the Skjema tab it will give you cell C6 from the tab selected in the drop down, etc.